# How to test React Native app on iPhone on Linux Mint without iPhone?

Tags: ios, linux, react-native

I am developing a mobile app using React Native on my PC laptop (Asus) with Linux Mint for operating systems. I am using VS Code as my IDE. I can successfully emulate an Android device on my laptop, but I am not sure how to test my app on an iPhone.

I have read that there are a few ways to do this. One way is to use a virtual machine (VM) running macOS. Another way is to use a service like Expo Snack that allows you to run your app on an iPhone simulator on the browser.

I do not own an iPhone,
I would appreciate any advice on how to test my React Native app on an iPhone on Linux Mint without an iPhone.

Tried the Expo Snack and Expo Go

but I want to emulate on iPhone on my Laptop

Comment: You can't emulate an iOS device without macOS.